# Flutter vs React Native (for building IoT Applications)

Tags: communication, mobile-applications

Good day Experts! I need your valuable suggestions regarding a very important decision in my development life. I need to know which framework is best suitable for IoT applications like communicating with BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices/microcontrollers (while supporting both ios and android platforms without going into problems and without doing anything extra), Classical Bluetooth communications, MQTT and HTTP communications easily and efficiently, Firebase integration and IoT platforms integration (AWS,Google IoT core) and all other IoT related stuff :)

Comment: Will see when new SDK comes but I am asking about the current situation. Please be kind with your answer

Comment: Hi @user12326, I think it's difficult to answer this question as it is. You've mentioned Flutter and React Native in your title and a few other things in your post, but depending on exactly what your application is, it's hard to say. Most likely Flutter v React Native makes little difference because you'll still be using some protocol (e.g. MQTT) to communicate from phone to device, but it's difficult to say without more info. Be sure to [edit] and clarify.